# HTML tooltip not working when Bootstrap is imported

Tags: html, exist-db

I want to use an HTML tooltip and also import some features from bootstrap. The problem is that when I add:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$shared/resources/css/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.css"/>
```

Tooltips are not working anymore. I'm working in eXist-db and using exide, here is my HTML code:

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title data-template="config:app-title"> ...</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta data-template="config:app-meta"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="$shared/resources/images/exist_icon_16x16.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$shared/resources/css/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$shared/resources/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$shared/resources/scripts/loadsource.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$shared/resources/scripts/bootstrap-3.0.3.min.js"/>
  <html>
<head>  

<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
 
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 110%;
  left: 20%;
  margin-left: -60px; /* Use half of the width (120/2 = 60), to center the tooltip */
  visibility: visible;
  
}
</style>
</head>
    <body id="body">

        <div style="width: 20%; height: 90px; float: left; margin:10px">
        <h4>Original Text:</h4>
        <div data-template="letter:text_orig"/>
        </div>

    </body>
    
    </html>
</html>
```

Here is my letter.xql where I use tooltip:

```
declare function letter:text_orig($node as node(), $model as map())
{
    let $resource := collection('/db/apps/Tobi-oshki/data')
    let $xml_id := letter:text_people('/db/apps/Tobi-oshki/data')
    for $rs in $resource//tei:rs
    for $id in $xml_id
        return
            if (data($rs/@key) eq $id) 
            then 
                <html>
                <div class="tooltip">{$rs}
                <span class="tooltiptext">{letter:text_lem(data($rs/@key))}</span>
                </div>
               </html>
            else
                ("")
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not relying on the bootstrap version that ships with `shared-resources` (which is deprecated since exist v 5.3.0) its outdated and unmaintained.

I would suggest packaging you own preferred dependencies and css. As a last resort you can experiment with replacing the js and css files inside shared resources with later versions, to see if that fixes your problem.